# why is the footer overlapping the content and going over the text?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

So I'm trying to set the footer to stick to the bottom (and it does) but it overlaps some of my content and also is immediately seen when the page is open. I want it to sit at the bottom of the page and seen only when scrolled

**CSS**

```
content {
background-color: #ddd;
padding: 10px;
width: 99%;
font-family: 'Gill Sans';

overflow: hidden;
}

.contentTop {
    color: var(--third-color);
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
.contentBottom {
    color: var(--third-color);
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  
.flex-left {
    width: 55%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid var(--primary-color);
  }
  
  .flex-right {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid var(--primary-color);
    margin-top: 180px;
    margin-left: 100px;
  }
  


.footer {
position: fixed;
margin-top: 100%;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
text-align: center;
background-color: var(--secondary-color);
color: var(--third-color);
padding: 10px;
width: 100%;
font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
display: flex;
height: 100px;
}

.col-1 { 
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.col-2 {  
    font-size: 0.8em;
flex-grow: 1;
margin-top: -10px;
margin-right: 50px;
}

.col-3 { 
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-right: 30px;
```

I tried changing the position: attribute of the footer but it didn't work. Tried to set padding-bottom to the content but remains the same.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="flex-container"> 
    <div class="flex-left">
      <span class="contentTop"><h2>aaaaaaaa</h2><span><br>
        <span class="contentBottom"><p>aaaaaaaaaa      <br>
         aaaaaaaaaaa
         
          
      </span>
    </div>
      
      <div class="flex-right">
        <div class="contentImg">
        <h2><img src="progwebpic.webp" alt="propic1"></h2>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, then just erase `position: fixed;` from the footer and define `min-height: calc(100vh - 100px)` (i.e.  full window height minus height of your footer) for your contents.

Comment: Hey! I tried you fix but apparently if i do the footer does actually stick to the bottom of the page but only on the right half. (its all compressed in the right half)

Comment: You didn't post your complete code so it's impossible to tell you any more. But from what you describe it sounds as if the fotter were in a container that only spans the right half of the window.